# Why this set satisfies the interior sphere condition? [Solved]

Tags: analysis

Consider the subset $\Omega\subset\mathbf{R}^n$,
$$\Omega=\{x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbf{R}^n;x_n>\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)\},$$
where $\varphi$ is a Lipschitz continuous function, that is, $\Omega$ is a unbounded set, bounded for a Lipschitz graph.

Why this set satisfies the interior sphere condtion?

Interior sphere condition means that for each $z\in\partial\Omega$, there is a ball $B_r(\xi)$ satisfying $\partial B_r(\xi)\cap\overline\Omega=\{z\}$.

Comment: What is the "interior sphere condition"?

Comment: I edited the question with the definition!

Comment: I am not sure that your condition is the standard interior sphere condition.

Comment: Yes, in this form, this condition seems not to hold for $\Omega$, even with *constant* $\varphi$.. anyway, what is $\xi$?

Comment: Im sorry, I repaired the definition. $\xi$ is a point of $\Omega$. This condition means that for each point $z$ in the boundary, you can construct a ball insided $\Omega$, that the boundary of this ball intersect only the point $z$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is straight analysis, so I've removed the differential-geometry and pde tags.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284562/interior-sphere-condition?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set does certainly not satisfy the interior sphere (or interior ball) condition in general, as the example $\varphi (x) = |x_1| + \ldots + |x_{n-1}|$ shows. This functions is $1$-Lipschitz, but the condition is violated at $0$.

Comment: I need to use a Hopf Lemma in this set. You know how can i use this without the interior ball condition?

Comment: Maybe you just need it almost everywhere? Lipschitz functions are differentiable a.e., that should give you the condition a.e. At points of non-differentiability like $0$ in the example you already have problems writing down the statement of the Hopf lemma, since there is no well-defined normal vector at these points.

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas Geyer.