# Dirichlet problem for Poisson equation in frequency domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Assume the Dirichlet problem for the Poisson equation in $I=(-1,1)$
\begin{equation*}
    \tag{$\dagger$}
    \begin{cases}
    u''= -f & \text{in} \quad I\\%\equiv (-1,1)\\
    u = 0 & \text{on}  \quad \partial I \equiv \{-1,1\}
    \label{eq:bvp}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and let $f\equiv c$ in $I$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f\equiv0$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus I$. Then, the solution can be recovered in closed form as
\begin{gather}
u = \frac{c}{2}\big(1-x^2\big) \quad \text{in} \quad \overline{I}
\end{gather}
Now, take the Fourier expansion of $u,f$
\begin{gather}
u(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{u}(k)e^{i\pi kx} \quad,\quad f(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(k)e^{i\pi kx}
\end{gather}
The BVP \ref{eq:bvp} in frequency domain reads
\begin{equation*}
    \tag{$\star$}
    \begin{cases}
    \hat{u}= \dfrac{\hat{f}}{\pi^2k^2} & \text{for}\ k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}\\
    \hat{u} =\ ? & \text{for}\ k=0
    \label{eq:bvp_freq}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Since $f$ is constant we have that $\hat{f}$ is zero almost everywhere except at $\hat{f}(k=0) = c$. Thus, we obtain $\hat{u} \equiv 0$ which implies $u \equiv 0 \ \text{in} \ \overline{I}$.

**Question a.** What went wrong?
I guess that we must have [$\hat{f}(k=0) =0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289746/fourier-transform-poisson-equation-exercise), but why?

**Question b.** If $\hat{f}(k=0) =0$ is a strict requirement, does that mean that we cannot solve \eqref{eq:bvp} in frequency domain? If yes, how could we reformulate it?

Cheers!

**Update 1.** After the comment of @Rahul, I think a possible way to go through could be to extend $f$ to take the value of zero at the boundary $\partial I$. Then, proceed with mollifying the extended function, taking the Fourier transform of this smooth approximation and passing to the limit. I haven't tried that yet. But.. isn't there any simpler way!?

Comment: Is really $\{ e^{ikx} \mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ an orthogonal Schauder basis on $(-1,1)$? Shouldn't you either take $I=(-\pi,\pi)$ or change to $e^{i2\pi kx}$?

Comment: @md2perpe I think you mean $\{e^{i\pi kx} \vert k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ for $I=(-1,1)$, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right; it should be just $\pi$.

Comment: @md2perpe Ok then, I am updating the question correspondingly.

Comment: What went wrong is that you have assumed $u''=-f$ everywhere, but the equality holds only in the interior of $I$. If you extend the closed-form solution to be periodic, as required for the Fourier series, you find that at the boundary $u''$ is a delta function.

Comment: @Rahul Could you somehow elaborate on this please? Then how should I formally express the problem to make it solvable?